# 403 error on facebook integratioin using SLRequest

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I don't know whether the permissions i gave is right or not please help me with this

```
ACAccountStore *account=[[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
ACAccountType *accountType=[account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];`enter code here`

NSDictionary *options = @{
                          ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"800285683347740",
                          ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"email",@"read_stream",@"user_likes", @"user_videos"],
                          ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends
                          };




[account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

    if (granted==YES) {

        NSArray *accounts=[account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

     ACAccount *facebookAccount=[accounts lastObject];
        NSDictionary *parameters=@{@"message":@"My First ios7 facebook posting"};
        NSURL *Url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"];

        SLRequest *request=[SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:Url parameters:parameters];

        request.account=facebookAccount;
        [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {

            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error");
            }else if([urlResponse statusCode]>=200 &&[urlResponse statusCode]<=300){
                NSLog(@"success");

            }else{
                NSLog(@"The status code :%d",[urlResponse statusCode]);
            }

        }];

    }else{
        NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);

    }
}];
```

Comment: can u show ur error report

Comment: 2014-10-27 15:30:11.235 FacebookPost[964:1303] The status code :403 this print statement of status code no error shown

Comment: partha plz show the full error report , now u only show the code type : 404,403,200, etc.., i need the error report

Comment: there is no error in the compiling

Comment: give me the mail id i will send the project so that u can review the code

Comment: k give some time , i run your code and tell to u